# Proxy For org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator:invoke:289

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jboss7.x, spring-data-jpa

I am performing benchmark testing for the application that i am currently working on. After a lot of iteration, we could identify that the time taking component.

Its a web based application using Spring Data JPA with hibernate as persistence provider.

From the monitoring tool we found that class `Proxy For org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator:invoke:289` is where a lot time spent when running more number(2000) of concurrent threads.

Kindly let me know the possible cause and solution please.

Below are the versions i am working with
Spring - 4.1.7.RELEASE
Hibernate - 4.2.15.Final
Spring Data JPA - 1.8.0.RELEASE
Below is the drilled down call graph

[image: Drill Down Call Graph]

Comment: 2000 threads sounds rather many? Any reason that number is so high?

Comment: Doing a performance test and looking for 5000 concurrent users.

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to find out about the pooling settings for your DataSource. With 5000 trying to create a transactional EntityManager, and thus trying to aquire a database connection, you probably max out your connection pool pretty fast and then get stalling threads.

Comment: The datasource pool size is set to 5000 in JBOSS AS 7.x. I could see that the connections are release back to the pool properly and adequate connections are available in pool.

Answer (score 1):

`SharedEntityManagerCreator` is creating a fresh `EntityManager` instance for that particular thread. If you work with JPA, that's what's supposed to happen as an `EntityManager` by definition of the spec is not thread-safe.

The line number you posted implies that it's the reflective method call on the `EntityManager` instance is taking that much time. So I'd inspect what method actually gets called, what it does and why it takes so long. `SharedEntityManagerCreator` is basically just forwarding the call.

Comment: Agreed and thanks for the information. But why does the time taken to create SharedEntityManagerCreator keeps increasing as the no of threads increase. It takes about a minute for 1000 concurrent threads.

Comment: Could you profile which part of the call is taking so long. Which version of Spring Framework are you using?

Comment: Spring Version - 4.1.7.RELEASE

Comment: Edited my question with the call graph after monitoring the app.

Comment: What do the nested calls look like? Line 289 of `SEMC` is a comment in Spring 4.1.7, so there seems to be a mismatch here.

Comment: I think Spring Data JPA version 1.8.0.RELEASE still refers to Spring ORM version 4.0.9.RELEASE. I hope i should exclude while building and try.

Comment: With Spring-orm 4.1.7 RELEASE, drill down points to Proxy For org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator:invoke:291

Comment: Oliver, kindly let me know are there any updates for me?