# Spring JpaTransactionManager takes 95% of the response time

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working on a RESTFull application that uses Spring JPA with hibernate as persistence provider.

During performance test i see that 95 % of the time consumed is in JPATrnasactionManager.

When i drilled down to see which class takes time, i found that method
`org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator:invoke` consumes 95% of the response time.

I have configured all my Service class as @Transactional

Comment: Isn't the database response slow?

Comment: No, MySQL is the DB i am working with and the max response time in DB is 150ms.

Comment: Can you post a sample somewhere along with details of the results you have obtained?

Comment: You might want to avoid posting the very same question over and over again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517349/proxy-for-org-springframework-orm-jpa-sharedentitymanagercreatorinvoke289

Comment: Sure Oliver, was trying to find solution by some means.